# regex re.compile, can't get it work

Tags: python, regex

I tried the following:

```
title = 'Die.Simpsons.S02.German'
season = re.compile('.*S\d|\Sd{2}|eason\d|eason\d{2}.*')
test = season.match(title)
print test
```

but I always received 'none'

Comment: What you are trying to achieve?
Please add expected result or explain in details.

Comment: For one thing `\Sd{2}` should be `S\d{2}`, otherwise you're matching one non-whitespace character and two literal ds. Please use an online regex debugger to explore what your expression actually does.

Comment: Actually the regex works for me. P3.5 .

Comment: This one should work (and is more readable) `re.compile('.*(S|Season|eason)\d{1,2}.*')`

Comment: I just think OP does not know how to print the match value: `if test: print test.group()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basing on your variable name I assume you are interested in the season number, not in the whole title. If I'm right it should look like this:

```
title = 'Die.Simpsons.S02.German'

# This will match Die.Simpsons.S1, Die.Simpsons.S01, Die.Simpsons.Season1 etc ...
reg = re.compile('.*(S|Season|eason)(\d+)')

# get only the season number, group(0) gives full match, group(1) first '()' and so on
season = reg.match(title).group(2)

print season # prints '2'
```

Instead of `reg.match` you could also use `reg.search`, then you don't need to have `.*` at the beginning:

```
reg = re.compile('(S|Season|eason)(\d+)')
season = reg.search(title).group(2)
```

//EDIT
Fixed after Thomas comment

Answer (score 0):

Using this code works:

```
import re

regex = r".*S(eason)?\d{1,2}.*"
test_str = "Die.Simpsons.S02.German"
matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches):
    matchNum = matchNum + 1

    print ("Match {matchNum} was found : {match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, match = match.group()))
```

See [demo](https://repl.it/EZfH/0).